# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

Tags: c#, json

I installed `Newtonsoft.Json` from nuget package.

But I am getting below error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can you please let me know what is the reason behind this and how to resolve the same ?

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified": isn't that clear enough?

Comment: where it is finding the file ? I have already checked the path from reference and dll is present there

Comment: Is the dll in the same folder as the executable? that's usually where it should be

Comment: yes in same folder :(
Do I need to make changes in GAC ?

Answer (score 0):

Check in Package.config, you are having 8.0 version

```
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Try adding the below in web.config

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Also, if you are having any older version of dll in project location, remove it

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. But I get this error whenever I add a new project to my legacy application. Below is what I do to fix the problem:

1. Update the project file (.csproj for c#) and add the below to the first property group which contains Configuration, Platform, ProjectGuid properties:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

2. Remove the binding redirects
3. Upgrade to the latest newrelic package

This always worked for me